# Doesn't this article about $1$-forms contradict itself?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am studying the first page of [this article here](https://math.colorado.edu/~jnc/lecture1.pdf).

The article defines a differential $1$-form to be a smooth map $\alpha : TM \to \mathbb R$ ($TM$ here is the tangent bundle) such that for $m \in M$ the point $\alpha (m)$ is a linear functional $T_m M \to \mathbb R$.

But then shortly afterwards the author writes that the $1$-forms $dx_i$ are the $i$-th projection: $dx_i (v) = v_i$.

But these $dx_i$ do not appear to be evaluated at any point $m \in M$. Isn't this contradicting the definition given earlier?

> Please could someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: It does the same thing at every point.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So it's evaluated implicitly?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean the author evaluates the $dx_i$ at some point $m \in M$ but does not say so in the article. Writing $dx_i$ when he is really using $dx_i (m)$.

Comment: That paper never says $\alpha (m)$....

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to get anywhere in geometry, you are going to have to learn to be more flexible with your notational qualms. I wish this were not the case, but this is the culture of the field.

Here, in order to make sense of $dx_i(v)$, you must first realize that $v$ is supposed to be a vector, in order to make sense of projection. Since it is standing in for an element of the tangent bundle, it is not a vector. But it is contained in some fibre of the manifold, so it can be reinterpreted as a vector in the tangent space at some point $m$. So $dx_i(v)=v_i$ really means $dx_i((m,v))=v_i$, but the $m$-dependence is suppressed because $m$ depends completely on $v$.

[Of course, all of this is happening with respect to coordinates! And these coordinates are not even uniquely defined, so you must either slog through a well-definedness argument or believe that $dx_i$ is even a thing that makes sense.]

Comment: To clarify the last paragraph, $dx_i$ is not a thing that makes sense without a choice of coordinates.

Comment: @Mike: Isn't it true that to define $dx_i$ you need a particular choice of coordinates, but after you define it, it's just a 1-form, independent of coordinates?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense in whatever open set $U$ the coordinate function $x_i: U \to \Bbb R$ makes sense in. I just wanted to clarify that we need coordinates $x_i$ to have a "$dx_i$"; it only exists once we pick the $x_i$ to take a derivative of. (I hope this parses. I'm agreeing with you.)

Comment: It makes sense to me, we'll have to wait on word from the OP :P

Comment: I'm sorry to say but your answer does not make anything clearer to me. I already know that the one forms $dx_i$ are linear functionals when restricted to each tangent space. What I am asking is: Given the definition of $1$-form shouldn't the $dx_i$ stand for a global $1$-form that is evaluated? But the evaluation point $m$ in the manifold $M$ is completely omitted. So maybe I am misunderstanding the article. In other words: I know that $dx_i$ is the restriction of "something" but I don't know what that something is.

Comment: Disregard. Disregard. I think your answer does make it clear: The global $\alpha$ whose domain is the tangent bundle is also $dx_i$ just with a different domain. Right, this is what you're saying?

Comment: @self-learner: Yes, $dx_i$ agrees with certain global 1-forms in an open neighborhood of $m$ (which is uniquely specified by $v$). But while it is possible to think of $dx_i$ as the restriction of something, I find that it is not so helpful. Rather I think of $dx_i$ as an object that makes sense in the context of a specific coordinate chart, and which in that context I lets me do purely formal computations with differential forms, rather than having to think about what they really are (equivalence classes of linear combinations of tuples of smooth sections of linear maps of derivations...).